# How do I make a subroutine that will receive a character and print it to the screen.in TASM

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm

I am a complete beginner in assembly and I wanted to make a subroutine that will receive a character from the calling program, and then display the character at the current cursor location. And then update the cursor to the next screen location. Is there a way to get the coordinates of the cursor, and is there a way to print a character at the coordinates of the cursor. Also how can I update the cursor to the next screen location?

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64
.DATA


.CODE

begin:

mov ah, 2
mov bh, 1
mov dh, 12
mov dl, 40
int 10h

END begin
```

I wanted to try putting the cursor in the middle, however the code that I put would not put the cursor in the middle. I wanted to put it in the middle because I thought this would be similar to the way you would update the cursor to the next screen location, only you add one to the x coordinate. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read thru the services offered by [int 10h](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10.html)?

Comment: Do you mean the DOS/BIOS text output cursor?Almost all output char services will output it at current cursor position, and update it to next char, so you are sort of trying to do what it does automatically, if you use some of those services. Only your requirement to start in the middle of screen is worth of additional BIOS service call, after that you can output characters (int 10h,ah=0Eh), or even whole string (DOS int 21h,ah=9), to save on separate service calls (both BIOS and DOS services were extremely slow on real PC, so most of the apps did rather write directly to video memory instead).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I took a look, I saw that I could use ah=03h but one of the parameters was bh=page number, what is the purpose of have that?

Comment: When the video display is set to text mode (ie no graphics), there is enough video memory to support multiple text pages.  While only 1 page can be displayed at a time, you can write to one of the "other" pages, then use `ah=05h` to quickly flip to a new page.  For most people, the page is always set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Since this issue seems to be resolved, I'm moving the comments to an Answer so this question can be closed.

[int 10h](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10.html) has a number of functions, including ones that allow you to read/write the cursor position as well as outputting characters.  Given that OP's original code uses int 10h (presumably there was a reason for that), this seems like the best approach.

As Ped7g mentions, there are also DOS interrupts that may suit your needs as well.  If performance is critical, there are also ways to write directly to video memory that are faster than dos/bios interrupts, but this may be more complicated than needed for your current project.

Note: A number of the `int 10h` services use `bh` to specify the page number.

When the video display is set to text mode (ie no graphics), there is enough video memory to support multiple text pages. While only 1 page can be displayed at a time, you can prepare one of the "other" pages, then use `ah=05h` to quickly flip to a new page.  This is an uncommon usage.  For most people, the page is always set to 0.